# How can $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^4}{z^5-z-1}dz$ be computed?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm going through some practice prelim exams, and one of the questions asks to compute
$$
\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^4}{z^5-z-1}dz.
$$

The integrand is not quite in the form $f'/f$ to count zeroes and poles inside the circle. I wanted to compute resides, but finding the poles at which to calculate them seems more difficult than usual. What is the more doable approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the substitution $w = \frac{1}{z}$ so that $-\frac{dw}{w^2} = dz$. The integral becomes (the negative sign goes away when we cancel it with the new orientation of the circle)
$$
\int_{|w| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{w^{-6}}{w^{-5} - w^{-1} - 1}dw
$$
which is
$$
\int_{|w| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{w - w^5 - w^6}dw
$$
The only root of the new denominator inside the new circle is 0, so you can just use residue theory from here.

Comment: Thanks, so it evaluates just to $2\pi i$.